# How to disable an svg tag based on any condition?

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

How can I disable an svg tag based on a condition in Angular?

Tried with [disabled]="true" but does not work for me. Adding a sample code down below.

```
<span>
<svg role="presentation" (click)="show = !show">
    <use [attr.xlink:href]="show ? '#arrow-top' : '#arrow-bottom'"></use>
 </svg>
 </span>
```

Comment: Disabled means do you mean you want to hide based on show variable?

Comment: @Navnath Jadhav
I want to disable the mouse pointer so that click wont work.

Comment: What would it look like if it was disabled? The disabled property is [an HTML only thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)

Comment: pointer-events: none; to disable the mouse.

Comment: On which condition you want to disable click? based on show variable?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to disable click based on showSVG  variable.

In ts.

```
showSVG = true;
```

In template:

```
<span>
Show/hide
  <svg [style.pointerEvents]="showSVG ? 'auto' : 'none'" role="presentation" (click)="show = !show">
      <use [attr.xlink:href]="show ? '#arrow-top' : '#arrow-bottom'"></use>
  </svg>
</span>
```